# delete rows when a column has conditions in two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, `table_a`, and `table_b`.
i need to delete all rows from `table_a`, with the following, which works for me (until the and statement): 
(etid is is an integer number, in `table_a`)

```
delete m1 
from table_a m1
inner join table_a m2 on m1.etid = m2.etid and m1.id <> m2.id
where m1.gid = 198 and (here i need to make sure that each row with etid that fulfills above criteria and will be deleted, is also of type 'product', info which is stored in table_b)
```

`table_b` has two columns:
`nid`, and `type`

The distinct values of column `type` are two: `'product'` and `'raw'` 
`nid` is the int number that is stored in column `etid` of `table_a`.

I think I must add another join, and also the in statement, so as to select only the appropriate rows... How should the above snippet be altered? I would like to find out also the most performant way to do this, in terms of speed of execution time

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=c16369b42847fbfb9a609e613945fc01

sample data above.

***Expected output***:

```
+----+------+---------+-----+
| id | etid |  title  | gid |
+----+------+---------+-----+
| 1  | 120  | Title1  | 198 | <-row that must be deleted
| 2  | 121  | Title2  | 55  |
| 3  | 120  | Title1  | 674 |
+----+------+---------+-----+
```

***Final output***:

```
+-----+------+---------+-----+
| id  | etid |  title  | gid |
+-----+------+---------+-----+
| 2   | 121  | Title2  | 55  |
| 3   | 120  | Title1  | 674 |
+-----+------+---------+-----+
```

Comment: Sample data and expected output would help.

Comment: sure, preparing them now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another join to `table_b`:

```
delete m1 
from table_a m1 
inner join table_a m2 on m1.etid = m2.etid and m1.id <> m2.id
inner join table_b b on b.nid = m1.etid
where m1.gid = 198 and b.type = 'product'
```

Comment: i think this is what i was missing, another join, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query.

```
DELETE M1 ,TABLE_A
FROM  M1
INNER JOIN TABLE_A M2 ON M1.ETID = M2.ETID AND M1.ID <> M2.ID
WHERE M1.GID = 198 AND M1.ETID IN (SELECT NID FROM TABLE_B TYPE= 'product');
```